# Difference between First order condition of convex and quasiconvex optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

What is the difference between the First order condition for testing whether a differentiable function is convex and case 2 whether a adifferentiable function is quasiconvex?

Both State the same thing i feel.
It is stated in Boyd & Vandenberghe's "Convex Optimization" that if f:Rn→Rf:Rn→R is differentiable, then ff is quasiconvex if and only if

f(y)≤f(x)⟹∇f(x)T(y−x)≤0f(y)≤f(x)⟹∇f(x)T(y−x)≤0, ∀x,y∈domf,∀x,y∈domf,
where domfdomf denotes the domain of f.

Which i understand is the same for convex.

Part 2 of my question: How in general other than this do we test if a function is quasiconvex.I read somewhere that the sublevel sets have to be finite or something for the sublevel sets to be convex.Could you give an intuition behind quasiconvex functions?

Comment: Your understanding that "is the same for convex" is simply incorrect.  The textbook refers you to (3.2), which says that $f$ is convex iff for all $x$ and $y$ in the domain, $f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^{T}(y-x)$.  This isn't the same as (3.20) in Boyd and Vandenberghe.

Comment: What you wrote is for testing whether a function is convex or not whereas what i wrote is for testing whether a particular solution is optimal or not